# How can I block network access for a firefox addon>

Tags: firefox

The dark mode app is giving me annoying news updates that I do not wish to see.  I don't like apps pestering me with update changelogs, which is why I have started to disable automatic updates for most software and apps since they all seem to do it nowadays.  How can I block this app from accessing the internet so that it doesn't ever notify me about this useless info again?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the addon is very probably searching update info on its author/publisher website (here https://darkreader.org), you could simply block it (while blocking any application) to reach this address.

This could be done using many different methods, depending your system, browser, either:

- you could edit the Host file,
- set up a firewall rule,
- using Chrome or Firefox (at least) there are extensions to blacklist some sites,
- using Windows Family Safety on Windows 10/11,
- or even blocking this site on your router/box...

Example of how-to:

https://www.cisdem.com/resource/how-to-block-websites-on-windows.html

*Of course, when done you won't be able to voluntarily reach this address using your browser for instance - but I guess you could temporarily disable the rule.*

Comment: I don't see an option in the advanced firewall settings to create an outbound rule to block websites, only IP addresses.  Since IP addresses can change, it would be best to block the domain name.

Comment: Agreed, sorry, didn't realize. IP *can* change, but probably not so often - it's maybe not a problem if you're happy for 'only' the next 2 years ;-)